# Parsing error: 'import' and 'export' may appear only with 'sourceType: module'

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

Im currently working with Google Cloud Functions and Firestore. But i run into problems when trying to get data from a parent document. I have searched the issue on the internet, but it seems that no of the fixes suggested works for me.

The following is what i get in the terminal when i try to deploy.

```
/Users/macmini1/Documents/resould-firebase/functions/index.js
  24:1  error  Parsing error: 'import' and 'export' may appear only with 'sourceType: module'

✖ 1 problem (1 error, 0 warnings)

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! functions@ lint: `eslint .`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the functions@ lint script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/macmini1/.npm/_logs/2019-11-22T12_20_27_403Z-debug.log
```

So far i have concluded that it has something to do with "firebase-admin" i have required.
I have tried to update everything, and different ways to execute the same objective.
But nothing seems to works.

Here is my code.

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

var db = admin.firestore();
exports.createBid = functions.firestore.document('auctions/{auctionId}/bids/{bidId}').onCreate(async (snap, context) => {
    const bid = snap.ref;
    const auction = await getAuction(auctionId);

    return bid.set({
        test: auction.end_date
    }, {merge: true}).then(() => {
        console.log("Count is created! " + bidId);
        return null;
    }).catch((error) => {
        console.error("Counter Error writing document: ", error);
        return null;
    });
});

export async getAuction(auctionId) {
    if (!auctionId) return Promise.reject('no userId');
    const auctionSnap = await db.collection('auctions').doc(auctionId).get();
    return auctionSnap.data();
}
```

And here is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "functions",
  "description": "Cloud Functions for Firebase",
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "serve": "firebase serve --only functions",
    "shell": "firebase functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "8"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "firebase-admin": "^8.8.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^3.3.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "^5.12.0",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^4.0.1",
    "firebase-functions-test": "^0.1.6"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

And my .eslintrc.json has ecmaVersion 2017

Hope there is somebody out there who can point out what i am doing wrong :-)

Answer (score 0):

I have face the same issue
I have tried this and it worked for me.

```
parserOptions: {
ecmaVersion: 11,
sourceType: "module",
},
```

Check spaces properly Between {} and key value
.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your `.eslintrc.js` or `.eslintrc.cjs` file:

```js
  parserOptions: {
    ecmaVersion: "latest",
    ecmaVersion: 11,
    sourceType: "module"
  },
```