# Firebase Cloud Function increment counter in Firestore on CreateUser

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I would like to use Firebase Cloud Functions to update a value inside my Cloud Firestore database everytime a new user is created. This is how my `index.js` looks:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

export const accountCreate = functions.auth.user().onCreate(user => {
    console.log(user.data);
    
    const FieldValue = require('firebase-admin').firestore.FieldValue;
    var userCounterRef = db.collection('data').doc('userCounter');
    userCounterRef.update({ count: FieldValue.increment(1) });
});
```

**Problem:**
If I run `firebase deploy` I get this error:

> 3:1  error  Parsing error: 'import' and 'export' may appear only with 'sourceType:
> module'
>
> ✖ 1 problem (1 error, 0 warnings)
>
> Error: functions predeploy error: Command terminated with non-zero
>
> exit code1

This is my `eslintrc` file:

```
module.exports = {
  root: true,
  env: {
    es6: true,
    node: true,
  },
  extends: [
    "eslint:recommended",
    "google",
  ],
  rules: {
    quotes: ["error", "double"],
  },
};
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: What does your `eslintrc` file say?

Comment: @b2m9 I updated the quesiton

Comment: The error might refer to [parser options](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring/language-options#specifying-parser-options). Worth a try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add this to your config file:

```
{
   "parserOptions": {
      "sourceType": "module",
   }
}
```

Comment: what exactly is my config file ? And where do I add this?

Comment: Probably package.json in your case. Have a read here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58994784/parsing-error-import-and-export-may-appear-only-with-sourcetype-module

Comment: that was actually it. But had to add this into my `eslintrct.js` not my `package.json``